# Django: where to store functions common to all apps

Tags: django

I am new to django I have some functions, which will be used by all the apps in the project, I don't know where to store those files and how to call them.

Is there a recommended way for storing those files in the project.

Comment: create a package next to your app, name it for example `handlers`, and inside all your apps, you may call it that way: `from handlers import function_name`

Comment: @Lemayzeur "create a package " is it a folder? or is there any function like django-admin to create it

Comment: create a package or python package means: create a folder, and add an empty file in it `__init__.py`, and inside `__init__.py` you create all your functions

Answer (score 13):

Create a python package next to your django application. The directory structure should be something similar to:

```
django_app/
    django_app/
       __init__.py
       apps.py
       settings.py
       urls.py
       views.py
       wsgi.py
    sub_app/
       __init__.py
       apps.py
       urls.py
       views.py
    utils/
        __init__.py
        module_one.py
        module_two.py
```

Here the folder `utils` is the package containing all your helper functions. For using the functions defined in `__init__.py` you can use `from utils import function_name`. For functions defined in other files like `module_one.py` you can use `from utils.module_one import function_name`.

Note: `__init__.py` file is compulsory for a python package. Even if there are no functions defined in it an empty file with the name `__init__.py` should be present in the folder for the folder to be classified as a python package.