# How and where to run (heavy) functions in the server for a django web app / where to store them

Tags: python, django, function

I am quite beginner to Django and I am confronted with this question.

provided I have the following structure:

```
django_app/
    django_app/
       __init__.py
       asgi.py
       settings.py
       urls.py
       views.py
       wsgi.py
    loaddata_app/
       >migrations
       __init__.py
       admin.py
       apps.py
       models.py
       test.py
       urls.py
       views.py
    >static
    >templates
       loaddata.html
```

My loaddata app is a super easy app that contains a text field to enter (paste) text.
The app should send the text to the server where a series of methods are applied to extract information out of the text and generate output data that will be presented to back to the user.

The first question is: If you have a bunch of methods in various files, where do you actually "store" those methods. And where are those methods supposed to be imported (if they need at all to be imported)?

What happens if those methods take (so to say) 10 minutes to run? is the connection still maintained with the browser of the user in the meanwhile?

So looks the simple app:
[image]

NOTE:
The question is partially answered here. But it is not entirely clear where those utils are imported and run in order to process the data.
[Django: where to store functions common to all apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51165037/django-where-to-store-functions-common-to-all-apps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the view class for your particular URL which does this job of getting input text and then processing and showing output is in the `loaddata_app`, and you have a bunch of functions common that you require.

You can keep the function in a python package at the root level of your project. You can name the package as `utils` or `utilities` or even as `common`. You can then create a file `common_functions.py` to put all your functions in.

So your project structure would look something like this.

```
django_app/
    django_app/
       __init__.py
       asgi.py
       settings.py
       urls.py
       views.py
       wsgi.py
    loaddata_app/
       >migrations
       __init__.py
       admin.py
       apps.py
       models.py
       test.py
       urls.py
       views.py
    >static
    >templates
       loaddata.html
    >utils
       __init__.py
       common_functions.py
```

You can then import these functions (eg: func1, funct2) in your `loaddata_app/views.py` as `from utils.common_functions import func1, func2`

Hope I have answered your doubt.

You can also check how to create a python package in this [link](https://timothybramlett.com/How_to_create_a_Python_Package_with___init__py.html)

Now, to answer your second question about the time, by default when you are running a django application using the development server, ie, `python manage.py runserver` and the request - response takes 10 mins, the connection will be live and it will not timeout.

But, say, if you deployed this application in Heroku or behind any application gateway (from AWS or Azure, etc) then, there will be a timeout and the connection will not persist (ie, it will be terminated). By default for heroku, the timeout is 30 seconds. In such cases, you should use something like [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) to handle large tasks as background processes and still send some response to the user's browser or client.